# Link only works when opened in new tab/window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, hyperlink

I have a Rails app, and on one of my pages, the links only work when opened in a new tab for some reason.

I have a main controller which opens links to other controllers fine. When I'm in my locations controller, the links only open up in a new tab for some reason. The URL is correct, the only problem is that nothing happens when I simply click the link.

Here is my link:

```
<a id="menu_link" href="../">Menu</a>
```

The `href` is basically saying go back to the root of the site.

I have also tried:

```
<%= link_to({:controller => "main", :action => "home"}, :id => 'menu_link') do %>
  <li>Menu</li>
<% end %>
```

My routes.rb file:

```
root :to => "main#home"
match 'admin', :to => 'access#admin_index'
match 'locations', :to => 'ranch_locations#locations'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Comment: Sounds like a JS issue. What scripts are you using?

Comment: have you tried "link_to "root", root_path"?

Comment: @Dogbert your a legend thats all I have to say! I love you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not obvious. 
In my application I have Javascript which is set to scroll to an anchor, when the header is on another page (where these anchors are not present) then the links do not do anything.
I simply had to exclude that function.

Comment: could you be more specific? I think I'm finding the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713823/requests-keep-loading-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment66726293_39713823